# twilio node disconnect event

Tags: node.js, twilio

I need a callback url or callback function to be triggered when the phone call disconnects after creating a call with

```
client.calls.create({
  url: "my url" + order._id + '/0',
  to: store.notification_phone,
  from: myNumber
}, function (err, call) {
});
```

I'm not sure if I need to create the callback in the nodejs app that does the above call or in the nodejs express server that generates the twiml.

I found a .disconnect( handler(connection) ) under Twilio.Connection, but this doesn't appear to be available in my nodejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To get a callback via a webhook when the call ends you need to pass a [`statusCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter) to your call function as well.

```
client.calls.create({
  url: "my url" + order._id + '/0',
  to: store.notification_phone,
  from: myNumber,
  statusCallback: "/calls/callback"
}, function (err, call) {
});
```

You will then need to implement an endpoint in your express application that [receives the callback with all the parameters about the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#request-parameters).

`Twilio.Connection` and the `.disconnect(handler(connection))` that you found are part of the [Twilio Client JavaScript library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js) that lets you make calls in the browser, so are not part of the server side API helper.